# Why is this simple piece of code printing "6" instead of "36" into the console?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace methodsIntro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 6;
            Sqr(x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        static int Sqr(int x)
        {
            int result = x * x;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Just a simple method to Square an integer. I don't think there's anything wrong with the method but the program is still outputting "6"

Comment: Because your code ignores the value returned by `Sqr`.

Comment: you need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're passing x as value parameter not as a reference, so any changes you make to the variable in the method wont have any effect outside, you need to consume the result or obtain it:

```
x = Sqr(x);
```

Comment: ...or better yet, assign the result to a new variable: `var result = Sqr(x); Console.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: That's a possibility too @spender, depends on OP's needs.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

That's cause it's printing the local variable declared which holds the value 6 `int x = 6` and not the returned value from method. If you want `36` as result then you should change ti to `Console.WriteLine(Sqr(x));`. Also remeber, `Int` is a value type and thus it's `pass by value` and so the value of `6` gets copied to the method local variable.

You can store the returned value in same variable `x` and print it in console like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 6;
        x = Sqr(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Comment: Cheers for your help!

Comment: This doesn't truly answer why the observed behavior is so, though. It offers an alternative, which does solve the underlying problem, but doesn't explain  why using the `Sqr(x)` directly as an argument to `Console.WriteLine` works.

Comment: Also, I'd leave out the "pass by value" bits since references are passed by value as well.

Comment: @KennethK., that's not the question here ... right? *references are passed by value as well* since when exactly?

Comment: @Rahul Try passing a list for example to a method, see if the value will change.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/11/how-are-parameters-passed-in-c-are-they-passed-by-reference-or-by-value/

Comment: @KennethK., ok, so you mean the reference of a ref type ... but I meant the ref variable. * I'd leave out the "pass by value" bits* why? OP is expecting it other way and thus it's necessary to mention

Comment: Mabye the OP is expecting pass by reference, or maybe he just forgot to save the value off to a variable. There is not enough information in the question for either of us to make the correct assumption.

Comment: @Rahul *Also remeber, Int is a value type and thus it's pass by value*, the fact the int is value type changes nothing about the way it's passed, the thing is that even reference type variables are passed by value by default.

Comment: Fine, let's go with your assumption that he thought it was pass by reference. Then what was the point of assigning to `result` and then actually *returning* result. I mean, it's supposed to be pass by reference, so what's the point of having a return?

Comment: Pass-by-value doesn’t matter here at all… the result would be the same if it were `ref int x`.